# Why do mov reg,reg instructions reading the result of a load account for so many cycles with perf record?

Tags: linux, x86, profiling, perf, intel-pmu

I'm profiling my program in Linux using perf tool, when checking the report I found a place really confuse me. I attach few lines of the report below:

```
  0.94 :          451ab5:       mov    (%r15),%r8
  0.44 :          451ab8:       mov    0x40(%rsp),%r15
  0.45 :          451abd:       mov    (%rsi),%rsi
  0.14 :          451ac0:       mov    (%r8,%rdi,4),%edi
  5.41 :          451ac4:       prefetcht0 (%rsi)
  0.11 :          451ac7:       lea    (%r15,%rdi,4),%rdi
  0.34 :          451acb:       mov    (%rdi),%r8d
  5.62 :          451ace:       add    %r8d,%eax
  0.18 :          451ad1:       prefetchnta (%rbx,%r8,4)
 24.46 :          451ad6:       mov    %r8,%r11
  0.11 :          451ad9:       mov    %eax,(%rdi)
  0.05 :          451adb:       mov    0x4(%rdx),%eax
  0.02 :          451ade:       lea    0x0(,%rax,4),%edi
```

My confuse is why this line(`mov %r8,%11`) cost so much time, from my understanding this instruction only mov data in register `%r8` into `%r11`. The data in `%r8` is loaded in position *451acb*.

My guessing is this instruction (`mov    (%rdi),%r8d`) is only trigger a read action but didn't actually "block", when instruction need use the content of register `r8`, it "block" until the content be loaded into CPU cache.

**My question if my guessing correctly?**

CPU : Intel E5-2660 v4

Comment: I'm assuming this is on an Intel CPU (not AMD or VIA)?  I tagged intel-pmu because it's the hardware that chooses how to account cycles to instructions. 
 (Hard problem for superscalar out-of-order execution).  Anyway yes, it's normal that instructions consuming a load result get the blame if they have to wait, not the load itself.